# how to use atomicMin() in CUDA/C++

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu, atomic, gpu-shared-memory

I tried using `atomicMin` function in CUDA/C++ using shared memory, the output is always `0` irrespective of the data that I enter. Can anyone help me fix this, if there's some error in the syntax or my usage of pointers, or maybe I am using the function incorrectly.

Here's the code:

```
__global__ void npd(int *a, int *g)         
{   
    int index = threadIdx.x;

    __shared__ int d[N];

    d[threadIdx.x]=a[index];        

    __syncthreads();        

    int dd;
    int inn;
    int u;

    if( 0==threadIdx.x )
    { 
        for( int u = 0; u<16; u++ )
        {
            atomicMin( g, d ) ;     
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should either use `atomicMin` or do all the calculations in thread 0. In the second case you can just calculate the minimum locally.

Answer (score 2):

[As the documentation describes](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#atomicmin), the second input to the function should be a value, not a pointer.

You have not given any description of what your function does, so I can not help fix it, but something like

```
atomicMin( g, d[0]) ;
```

will compile, likely not doing whatever you are aiming for here.

Note: Always post complete compilable examples. And try to tidy your code. There is a double definition of `u` and the variable `index` is declared but never used.

Comment: You mean `d[u]`?

Comment: @Sebastian one would guess, but hard to know what OP wanted, 3 years ago.